# ActiveMQ Redelivery Police for a message

Tags: activemq-classic

Is it possible to use a redelivery policy for a single message in a queue? So different Messages in a queue can have different policys.

I found just a setting for the whole queue.

Best regards, Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Redelivery policies are applied to either all messages from all Queues or you can customize it a bit and have certain policies applied to messages from a distinct Queue but not a single message.